# optionals in swift, unwrapped required

Tags: swift

I am unsure why/how this works.  I have a method that I use to create NSManagedObject subclasses:

```
public func createWithPlacemark(placemark: CLPlacemark) -> AddressAnnotation {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("AddressAnnotation", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! AddressAnnotation

        return updateAnnotation(entity, withPlacemark: placemark)
    }

    public func updateAnnotation(annotation: AddressAnnotation, withPlacemark placemark: CLPlacemark) -> AddressAnnotation {
        annotation.address = placemark.subThoroughfare
        annotation.street = placemark.thoroughfare
        annotation.city = placemark.locality
        annotation.state = placemark.administrativeArea
        annotation.zip = placemark.postalCode

        if !placemark.name.isEmpty {
            annotation.name = placemark.name
        }
        else if placemark.areasOfInterest[0] as? String != nil{
            annotation.name = placemark.areasOfInterest[0] as! String
        }
        else {
            annotation.name = ""
        }

        annotation.latitude = placemark.location.coordinate.latitude
        annotation.longitude = placemark.location.coordinate.longitude

        return annotation
    }
```

As far as I can tell, both of these methods do not return an optional.  The insertNewObjectForEntityForName returns AnyObject, not AnyObject?.

When I call this code, it looks like this:

```
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
            geocoder.geocodeAddressString(string, completionHandler: {
                (placemarks, error) -> Void in

                // Check for returned placemarks
                if let placemarks = placemarks where placemarks.count > 0 {
                    let topResult = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark

                    let address = self.addressAnnotationLogic?.createWithPlacemark(topResult)


                    if address!.name.isEmpty {
                        address!.name = string
                    }


                }
            })
```

When I call createWithPlacemark, `address` is not an optional.  If I tried adding a `!` to the end of the line, I get a compile error.  That makes sense to me.

However, when I try to use the address in an if statement

```
if address!.name.isEmpty {
```

I am required to use the force unwrap.  Why is that?  The address variable is not optional to begin with since createWithPlacemark returns a value, not an optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bang!` is required because of the [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) you use in this line:

```
let address = self.addressAnnotationLogic?.createWithPlacemark(topResult)
```

When you use optional chaining, if any link in the chain is `nil`, the entire expression returns `nil`, and whether or not the result is `nil`, the expression always evaluates to an `Optional` value.

`addressAnnotationLogic?` indicates that `addressAnnotationLogic` is an `Optional` of some kind, which means that it may be `nil`. If `addressAnnotationLogic?` is `nil`, then the entire expression `self.addressAnnotationLogic?.createWithPlacemark(topResult)` will evaluate to `nil`. If it is not `nil`, `address` will still be an `Optional` value.

One suggestion would be to use the new `if let` syntax to unwrap all of the potential `Optional` values that are in your code, like this:

```
if let placemarks = placemarks where placemarks.count > 0,
   let topResult = placemarks[0] as? CLPlacemark,
   let address = self.addressAnnotationLogic?.createWithPlacemark(topResult) {
       if address.name.isEmpty {
           address.name = string
       }
}
```

That would be substantially less likely to produce a runtime error. Using the `!` is risky.

Comment: she said `address` is not an optional though, which I wonder how thats possible since she used optional chaining for `address`

Comment: `address` *is* an `Optional`, whether she knows it or not :) She is suffering from Optional Denial Syndrome. © 2015 letvargo